# Why is my WebApplicationFactory hanging for 5 minutes before timing out?

Tags: c#, integration-testing, .net-6.0

I'm trying to add some integration tests to my existing .net 6.0 project, but keep running into issues

Right now if I run the test, it hits the line `await host.RunAsync(CancellationToken.None);` in `Program.cs` and then just hangs forever and seemingly does nothing

Have I misunderstoof something? If not how can I troubleshoot this?

Program.cs

```
public /*static*/ class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        await host.InitialiseAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        await host.SeedAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        await host.RunAsync(CancellationToken.None); // hangs here
    }
}
```

Tests.cs

```
[Fact]
public void Test1Async()
{
    using (var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
        .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // set up servises
            });
        }))
    {
        var c = application.CreateClient(); // hangs here
    }
}
```

---

It does eventually time out and give me this error

> Message: 
> System.InvalidOperationException : Timed out waiting for the entry point to build the IHost after 00:05:00. This timeout can be modified using the 'DOTNET_HOST_FACTORY_RESOLVER_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS' environment variable.

> Stack Trace: 
> HostingListener.CreateHost()
> <>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0(String[] args)
> DeferredHostBuilder.Build()
> WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder) DelegatedWebApplicationFactory.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder) WebApplicationFactory`1.ConfigureHostBuilder(IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
> WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer() WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
> WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(Uri baseAddress, DelegatingHandler[] handlers) WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient(WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions options)
> WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient()
> UnitTest1.Test1Async() line 35

Comment: I am also facing same issue and need your quick help if possible please. 

I done have Main function in my case as its .net 6 and calling WebApplication    .CreateBuilder(args) directly and getting the same error.

*System.InvalidOperationException: Timed out waiting for the entry point to build the IHost after 00:05:00. This timeout can be modified using the 'DOTNET_HOST_FACTORY_RESOLVER_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS' environment variable.*

I appreciate any help on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue. Could not solve it. Also hangs at `CreateClient()` and drops dead after 5 minutes with same exception. I solved it by removing WebApplicationFactory usage and replacing it with TestServer instance which I built separately of the web host used in my Program.cs I know, not perfect, but you can build a method to reuse the config that builds the web host if required for reusability purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you didn't share the code for `BuildWebHost()` method I assume it is something like this `public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args)`.

If so then simply rename this method to `CreateWebHostBuilder`. Name of the method is important because `WebApplicationFactory` internally is looking for it.

Straight from the summary on the constructor:

```
/// The <see cref="WebApplicationFactory{TEntryPoint}"/> will find the entry point class of <typeparamref name="TEntryPoint"/>
/// assembly and initialize the application by calling <c>IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string [] args)</c>
/// on <typeparamref name="TEntryPoint"/>.
```

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Testing/src/WebApplicationFactory.cs#L24